# Is there any method similar to Golang's Scan() method (used for SQL) for Elasticsearch?

Tags: json, go, elasticsearch

I am new to both Go and ES. I want to convert the following piece of code:

```
query = `SELECT roll_no, name, school FROM students where roll_no = $1`
err = db.QueryRowContext(ctx, query, roll_no).Scan(&Student.ID, &Student.Name, &Student.School)
```

into something like the following Elasticsearch query:

```
str = fmt.Sprintf(`{"query": { "match": {   "roll_no" : %d  } } }`, roll_no)
b := []byte(str)
// calls retrieve method, which is shown below
```

I am connecting to ES using HTTP calls, but the following code is showing `http: panic serving [::1]:5574: EOF` error while parsing.

```golang
func retrieve(url string, b []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    request, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, bytes.NewBuffer(b))
    request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")

    client := &http.Client{}
    response, error := client.Do(request)
    if error != nil {
        panic(error)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)

    s := Student{}
    error = json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&s)
    if error != nil {
        panic(error)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Student: %v", s)

    return body, error
}
```

Is there anyway I can store it into an object by parsing?

Comment: What are you using to communicate with elasticsearch?

Comment: @mkopriva simple http calls to the port `:9200`

Comment: In that case you can read the HTTP response body, parse it, and decode it into "an object". How to do the parsing and decoding will depend on the response body's content mime type.

Comment: @mkopriva I'm actually new to both Go and Elasticsearch, and getting an error while parsing. Would you mind showing an example in reference to the code above?

Comment: If you encountered an error then you should include that in the question and you should also include the code that caused the error.

Comment: You're getting the error because `ioutil.ReadAll` reads the body till the end, and the body keeps track of that, it has a cursor. So when you then pass it to json.Decoder and attempt to decode a body whose cursor is at the end, you get EOF (end of file).

Comment: If you want both, raw bytes of the body and an instance of student, replace `json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&s)` with `json.Unmarshal(body, &s)`, i.e. unmarshal the output of `ioutil.ReadAll`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236124/discussion-between-pallab-and-mkopriva).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use Golang's Scan() method (normally used for SQL) in Elasticsearch?

Not at all.

Package database/sql needs a database driver and there isn't one for ES.

Comment: Thanks. I have modified the question now.